# I am getting Visualforce error like Unknown property 'wrapp' referenced in deletewrap

Tags: visualforce

I have written wrapper class and created visualforce page but i am getting error

"Unknown property 'wrapp' referenced in deletewrap".

```
public class DeletingCheckedRowsController{
 public list<WrapperClass>wrapp{get;set;}
 public Boolean bool{get;set;}
  public DeletingCheckedRowsController(){
    wrapp=new list<WrapperClass>();
    List<Account> acc=[select id, name from Account Limit 10];
    for(Account a: acc){
      wrapp.add(new WrapperClass(a)); 
     }
  }

public class WrapperClass{
  public Boolean checked{get;set;}
  public Account a{get;set;}
    public WrapperClass(Account acc, Boolean b){
       checked=b;
       a=acc;
     }
   }

public void del(){
List<Account>accToDel=new List<Account>();
for(WrapperClass w: wrapp){
  if(w.checked){
  accToDel.add(w.acc);

  }
}
 if(accToDel.size()>0){
     delete accToDel;
  }

  }
}
```

Visualforce code

---

```
<apex:page> 
 <apex:form> 
  <apex:pageBlock> 
   <apex:pageBlockButtons> 
    <apex:commandButton value="delete" action="{!del}"/> 
  </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapp}" var="w"> 
     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.checked}"/> 
      <apex:column value="{!w.a.name}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
     </apex:pageBlock> 
   </apex:form> 
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the controller attribute on apex:page. Add `controller="DeletingCheckedRowsController"` as you didn't add the controller you can't access it's property.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to tell the VF Page where you have implemented all the logic. And as you have implemented the functionality in above provided Custom Controller.
So here, add an attribute in `<apex:page>` tag like:`<apex:page controller="your_ControllerClass_Name">`

Refer this link for more info: [Controller Docs from Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller.htm)